# Why does a working monadic linkage between functions break, when I introduce a new argument that uses the Monad as a parameter?

Tags: haskell, types, monads, monad-transformers, state-monad

The following code:

```
-- tst2.hs - showing successful monadic linkage.

{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import Protolude
import Control.Monad.Extra  (unfoldM)

foo :: Monad m
    => Int
    -> m [[Int]]
foo n = evalStateT (traverse nxt [1..n]) 0
 where nxt _ = do s <- get
                  r <- bar s
                  put $ s + 1
                  return r

bar :: Monad m
    => Int
    -> m [Int]
bar n = unfoldM step n
  where step k = return $ if k > 0 then Just (k, k - 1)
                                   else Nothing

main :: IO ()
main = do xs <- foo 3
          print xs
```

works fine, producing this output:

```
Davids-Air-2:haskell-rl dbanas$ stack runghc tst2.hs 
[[],[1],[2,1]]
```

However, if I change the code slightly:

```
-- tst3.hs - showing breakage of monadic linkage.

{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import Protolude
import Control.Monad.Extra  (unfoldM)

data Dummy m = Dummy (Int -> m Int)

foo :: Monad m
    => Int
    -> Dummy m
    -> m [[Int]]
foo n d = evalStateT (traverse nxt [1..n]) 0
 where nxt _ = do s <- get
                  r <- bar s d
                  put $ s + 1
                  return r

bar :: Monad m
    => Int
    -> Dummy m
    -> m [Int]
bar n d = unfoldM step n
  where step k = return $ if k > 0 then Just (k, k - 1)
                                   else Nothing

main :: IO ()
main = do xs <- foo 3 $ Dummy (\n -> return n)
          print xs
```

I get the following compiler error:

```
Davids-Air-2:haskell-rl dbanas$ stack runghc tst3.hs 

tst3.hs:15:23: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘m’ with ‘StateT Integer m’
      ‘m’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          foo :: forall (m :: * -> *). Monad m => Int -> Dummy m -> m [[Int]]
        at tst3.hs:(11,1)-(14,16)
      Expected type: StateT Integer m [[Int]]
        Actual type: m [[Int]]
    • In the first argument of ‘evalStateT’, namely
        ‘(traverse nxt [1 .. n])’
      In the expression: evalStateT (traverse nxt [1 .. n]) 0
      In an equation for ‘foo’:
          foo n d
            = evalStateT (traverse nxt [1 .. n]) 0
            where
                nxt _
                  = do s <- get
                       ....
    • Relevant bindings include
        nxt :: forall p. p -> m [Int] (bound at tst3.hs:16:8)
        d :: Dummy m (bound at tst3.hs:15:7)
        foo :: Int -> Dummy m -> m [[Int]] (bound at tst3.hs:15:1)
   |
15 | foo n d = evalStateT (traverse nxt [1..n]) 0
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The solution turns out to be very simple, although it took me several hours to deduce:

```
          r <- lift $ bar s d

Davids-Air-2:haskell-rl dbanas$ stack runghc tst3.hs 
[[],[1],[2,1]]
```

I have a theory about this and would like confirmation:

The Monad operating in `bar` is different from the Monad operating in `foo`.
Specifically, the Monad operating in `foo` is the *lifted* version of the Monad operating in `bar`. (Lifted into a `StateT` context, to be precise.)

In the case of `tst2.hs` where there is no type linkage between the two `m`s (of `foo` and `bar`), this works perfectly.
However, in `tst3.hs` I've provided a type linkage between the two forcing them to be the same Monad.
And that is why the compiler complains.

My solution works, only because the Monad operating in `foo` really is the *lifted* version of the one operating in `bar`.
If the two Monads were completely unrelated then my solution would *not* work.

Is that all correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `foo` from `main`, you are saying that `Monad m` should be `IO`. Thus, you get a `Dummy IO` from `Dummy (\n -> return n)` (this could just be `Dummy return`, by the way). Then inside `foo`, you are calling `bar` with a `Dummy IO` argument, thus setting `m` to `IO` in `bar`'s `Monad m`. However, the call to `bar` is inside `StateT Int IO` instead of `IO`, hence the error.

As you discovered, you can call bar with `Dummy IO` and then lift the result into `StateT Int IO`. You are also correct to observe that there could be situations where this wouldn't work.

There's another solution that you may want to consider. If you don't actually care what monad your `Dummy` type needs (as seems to be the case), you can enforce that it works in all monads:

```
newtype Dummy = Dummy (Int -> (forall m. Monad m => m Int))
```

This requires the `RankNTypes` extension.

Comment: I am wondering if `(forall m. Monad m => m Int)` is actually isomorphic to `Int` (exploiting parametricity). I can't think of anything in that polymorphic type which is (non bottom and) distinct from `return someInt`.

Comment: @chi interesting observation. I suppose we'd need some other constraint(s) to motivate that technique.